Sum up Week to Date values in a versatile manner - Pandas
So every day I have to pull a report that gets data for yesterday's metrics, forecasted Saturday's metrics, and Week to date sums.
I want to write a Python code that automates the process.
I have most of the code done but I'm having issues with the week-to-date sums.
I want it to be versatile cause the sum will increase each day of the week. So if I run the code tomorrow, it will take into account all values from Sunday to Tuesday. If I run it on Friday, it will be Sunday to Thursday.
The data looks like this (dummy data):



Location
Metric
2024-09-04
2024-09-05
2024-09-06
...
2024-09-14




ABC1
Sales
123
12
14

15


ABC1
Profit
15
10
45

43



I want it to look like this:



Location
Metric
Yesterday
Saturday
Week to Date




ABC1
Sales
12
15
100


ABC1
Profit
10
43
120



So it doesn't matter when I run the code, it will be versatile enough to adapt to the dates/days.
I have the data for Yesterday and Saturday showing properly. But the sum is giving me 0s for WtD for every value.
So it looks more like this for every row:



Location
Metric
Yesterday
Saturday
Week to Date




ABC1
Sales
12
15
0


ABC1
Profit
10
43
0



df = pd.read_excel("Data.xlsx")
date_col = df.columns[3:]
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + pd.to_datetime(date_col, errors='coerce').tolist()
df.columns = df.columns[:3].tolist() + [d.date() for d in df.columns[3:]]
today = datetime.today().date()
yesterday = (datetime.today() - timedelta(days=1)).date()
week_start = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday())
saturday = week_start + timedelta(days=5)

if yesterday in df.columns:
    df_yesterday = df[['Location','Metric', yesterday]]
if saturday in df.columns:
    df_saturday = df[['Location','Metric',saturday]]
sunday = yesterday - timedelta(days=yesterday.weekday() + 1)
wtd = df.columns[(df.columns >= pd.Timestamp(sunday)) & (df.columns <= pd.Timesstamp(yesterday))]


please do not upload images of code/data/errors and provide a minimal reproducible example

Please [edit] your question to add your sample df and the expected output based on the sample as text, not as pictures.

Apologies, edited the post

One possible solution is to use melt to get the dates in a single column.
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Location', 'Metric'], value_name='value', var_name='date')
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.date

This gives a result as follows (note that the dates are changed slightly from the example data):
  Location  Metric        date  value
0     ABC1   Sales  2024-09-09    123
1     ABC1  Profit  2024-09-09     15
2     ABC1   Sales  2024-09-10     12
3     ABC1  Profit  2024-09-10     10
4     ABC1   Sales  2024-09-11     14
5     ABC1  Profit  2024-09-11     45
6     ABC1   Sales  2024-09-14     15
7     ABC1  Profit  2024-09-14     43

Now, we can compute the dates as before, and filter the data together with groupby to get the wanted aggregations:
today = datetime.today().date()  # 2024-09-11
yesterday = today - timedelta(days=1)  # 2024-09-10
next_saturday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday() - 5) # 2024-09-14
sunday = today - timedelta(days=today.weekday() + 1) # 2024-09-08

df_y = df[df['date'] == yesterday].groupby(['Location', 'Metric'])['value'].sum()
df_s = df[df['date'] == next_saturday].groupby(['Location', 'Metric'])['value'].sum()
df_ws = df[(df['date'] > sunday) & (df['date'] < today)].groupby(['Location', 'Metric'])['value'].sum()

Finally, we merge the resulting Series into a DataFrame:
df = pd.DataFrame({'Yesterday': df_y, 'Saturday': df_s, 'Week-to-date': df_ws}).reset_index()

Result:
  Location  Metric  Yesterday  Saturday  Week-to-date
0     ABC1  Profit         10        43            25
1     ABC1   Sales         12        15           135


That may work. Let me try it today. Thank you!

@Kael_1993: Did it work out for you?
